# Circle Mesh - Can't Adjust Vertex Count

Tags: mesh, vertices

I recently tried to create a circle mesh, which works fine. However I cannot change any of the **Add Circle** settings. It is all grayed out, so I cannot change how many vertices there are in the circle with the sliders.

Is anybody else having this issue? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found the answer! Go to **File > User Preferences > Editing > Undo**, and enable Global Undo. Problem solved! :)